# Copying files to a SSD without problems

Tags: permissions, hard-drive, backup, ssd, copy

I am planning to buy a SSD external disk with some terabytes of capacity.
I want to copy some files, repos, code, documents etc that I have in my ubuntu machine

In the past, I vaguely remember that sometimes I have had problems copying files to an external device, due to perhaps permissions, etc.

I suspect this is due to the filesystem of the devices I used.

I use a lot of containers too and sometimes these files are created inside the containers therfore the owner is not the same as the outside user

So what is a good way to ensure that I can copy my files without problem to an external SSD?

I believe that perhaps I have to format the disk first? (perhaps to ext4?)
(as commercial products, these devices have a label that says are only "assured to work in windows and mac")

Comment: If you want to use the device exclusively for Linux, you should definitely format it with a Linux filesystem (like `ext4` or `zfs`).

Comment: If you want to copy everything on the old disk and the partition(s) are formatted with a Linux file system one very easy way to do this is to use GParted and simply copy/paste the partition(s). Once on the new disk just resize as meets your needs. If a root file system is involved you will need to do this by booting a live iso like GParted live or the Ubuntu installation iso

Comment: If larger drive, be sure to use gpt. I think gparted still defaults to the old MBR(msdos) partition configuration. With gparted select gpt under device, advanced over msdos(MBR) default partitioning before starting.